# gnome-tweak-tool fails with error gtweak not found

Tags: 11.10, gnome-tweak-tool

I'm trying to run gnome-tweak-tool but it gives the following error:

> igor@BurnInHell:~$ python /usr/bin/gnome-tweak-tool~  Traceback (most
>   recent call last):   File "/usr/bin/gnome-tweak-tool~", line 25, in
>   
>       import gtweak ImportError: No module named gtweak

Where can I find the gtweak lib?

Thanks,
Igor

Comment: Have you installed using `sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool`

Comment: Yes I did. I tried to look for the dependencies but no luck.

Comment: Its run fine on Ubuntu, you can try couple of things, `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get remove --purge gnome-tweak-tool` and then install it again.

Comment: Have you solved your issue?

Answer (score 1):

Try to purge and reinstall again.

`sudo apt-get remove --purge gnome-tweak-tool && sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool`

Comment: This didn't solve it for me

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this workaround if your `/usr/bin/gnome-tweaks` file contains

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
```

Try changing it to

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
```